# Java Spring bean scopes: singleton vs application

Tags: spring

Could anyone explain the difference between these two Spring bean scopes?
I'm familiar with the Singleton pattern.

Would this be the only difference?
You can have a list of beans in the Spring container using application scope.

Also, are you able to run multiple web servers in one Spring container? If yes, that would be a reason to use the application scope over the singleton scope since otherwise the bean would get shared over the two servers.

Answer (score 8):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-application) explains it:

> This is somewhat similar to a Spring singleton bean but differs in two important ways: It is a singleton per ServletContext, not per Spring 'ApplicationContext' (or which there may be several in any given web application), and it is actually exposed and therefore visible as a ServletContext attribute

Comment: Hey Nizet, I am little confuse. Can you give some example, where an application have multiple ServletContext.

Comment: Re-read. A web app has only one ServletContext. But it can have multiple Spring application contexts (often, one root context and one child web context per Spring dispatcher servlet)

Comment: multiple spring application contexts means, we can have multiple spring configuration files, right .. And we can define the same bean in multiple file right.. with scoped to "application". Is it what you are trying to say. Plz help me to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In application scope, the container creates one instance per web application runtime. 
The application scope is almost similar to singleton scope. So, the difference is

*Application scoped bean* is singleton per ServletContext however *singleton scoped bean* is singleton per ApplicationContext. It means that there can be multiple application contexts for single application.

SINGLETON SCOPED BEAN

```
//load the spring configuration file
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

// retrieve bean from spring container
MyBean myBean = context.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class);
MyBean myBean2 = context.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class);

// myBean == myBean2 - output is true.
```